# Processing.js -- Programatically creating arc shapes (perhaps using SVG?)

Tags: svg, processing, processing.js

I'm a Processing programmer that recently started fiddling with Processing.js. As a personal exercise, I've been trying to port a few features from a past Processing project over to Processing.js... and I'm currently stumbling on custom shape creation.

In my previous project I had a custom shape class that created arc shapes such as the ones shown in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOSN.png) (with configurable *inner/outer radius*, and *start/end angles*). I had to create it from scratch because the **arc()** function in Processing doesn't really allow for this much control. My current goal is to **recreate such arc shapes dynamically on Processing.js**.

On the Processing.js reference, it says that it is [not possible to create a new shape, but SVG files can be loaded instead](http://processingjs.org/reference/PShape/). Of course, it is not feasible to create an internal SVG file every time I want to create a new shape, but generating a string representing the SVG code to be parsed would be an option.

So first question would be: **is it possible to create custom shapes in Processing.js in any other way but SVG files?** If not, then my second question would be: **is there any way we can "input" an XML string into the PShape class so it can be parsed as the SVG file would?**

One major assumption I'm making is that creating a shape will be more efficient than just drawing the vertices every cycle with *beginShape()/endShape()*... which might not be true, but I couldn't find supporting material on that either. Ultimately, third question would be: **doesn't it make more sense to just iterate over the vertices?**

I'm also assuming that Processing.js doesn't have this flexible arc functionality available (simply because Processing didn't). I'd be happy to be instructed otherwise, as it would definitely solve by problem for now... but I'd still like to learn more about custom shape alternatives in Processing.js, for a more general understanding.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't make a new shape, but that still leaves just making a class that uses `beginShape` and `curveVertex`/`bezierVertex` to draw exactly the same thing when told to draw itself. This should let you draw arbitrary things.

Comment: Yes... this is what I eventually resorted to. I spent a couple of days trying to get the SVG implementation to work. The "arc" component appears to be unimplemented for both SVG shape classes in Processing.js and Processing. I also tried to add the arc points directly, but it wouldn't parse the resulting SVG string because it was too big. In the end, iterating over the vertices was the only strategy that worked.